# JSON: Spring Boot Conditional Validation

Tags: json, validation, spring-boot

I have a POST API written in Spring Boot. I need to validate some data conditionally. For example, this is my JSON:

```
{
  "p1": false,
  "p2": true,
  "p3": false
}
```

The validation I am trying to achieve here is

- If `p1` is `false`, then `p3` should also be `false`.
- If `p1` is `true`, `p3` doesn't need to be `true`.

Is there some example of conditional JSON validation in Spring to refer from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom constraint for your object.

The rest end point.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doSomething", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> doSomething(@RequestBody @Valid MyObject myObject) {
```

The body POJO.

```
@MyConstraint(message = "p1 is false, p3 should also be false")
public class MyObject {

    private boolean p1;
    private boolean p2;
    private boolean p3;

   //getters and setters
}
```

The constraint annotation being used by `MyObject`

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyConstraintValidator.class)
public @interface MyConstraint {

    String message() default "Invalid object";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

The Validator that the constraint kicks off.

```
public class MyConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyConstraint, MyObject> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(MyObject value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        if (!value.isP1()) {
            return value.isP1() == value.isP3();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the fully qualified names of the ConstraintValidator and ConstraintValidatorContext classes?